# Python if in Statement Specifics

Tags: python, if-statement, padding

In short i have a list of items. lets say they have a name of Object1, Object2,....Object10,....Object20 And so on.

This list depending on use input changes starting points, for the example lets say the list packs in the names of all objects from Object18 up to Object28

Im using a statement to select these items from the stored list that goes:

```
for i in nuke.allNodes():
if i.name() in hiddenLists:
    i.setSelected(True)
else:
    i.setSelected(False)
```

Which works generally... trouble is because "in" (for inside the list) doesnt specify i want it to have to match an entire entry of the list, Instead of JUST selecting Object 18-28 it selects Object1 Object2 And Object 18-28 (reason being of course, Object18 and so on begin with Object1, and the 20s with a 2)

I cant pad the strings due to the fact that these are set names a program creates and have to stay the same. my only question is, is there a better operator than in that makes it have to match exactly rather than see Object1 within 'Object18'?

Comment: is hiddenLists a list or a string object?  If it is a list is it a list of strings or another object?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow:  `"this" in ["this_that"]` will return `False`.  What is the datatype of `hiddenLists`?

Comment: That's my confusion as well... unless hiddenLists is a string in which case "this" in "this_that" returns true.

Comment: Note that the if statement in your code can be removed completely and replaced with `i.setSelected(i.name() in hiddenLists)` (assuming the if statement worked as expected.

Comment: Your question is pretty hard to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like hiddenLists is a string (str) entered by the user. Use the `split` method on that string to make it a list first. Then the "in" clause will do what you want.

For instance, if the user enters a comma-separated list:

```
hiddenLists = [x.strip() for x in hiddenLists.split(",")]
if i.name() in hiddenLists:
    ...
```

Comment: Tommy wins. Sorry if it was a confusing post - I had thought it was a list, and it was at one point, but in getting the data from one place to the next due to the program im in it became a string and i didnt realize. Not sure whats yp with your code though tommy, However jsut using
    hiddenLists.split(",")
alone was perfect.